# Neo4J ServiceUnavailable always in same place. No idea why

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I've got a system that, when it is deployed, runs a lot of scripts to fill a Neo4J database. No CSV import, just regular queries creating tons of nodes and relationships.

Quite regularly, but not quite always, I get an error in one particular script, and I have no idea why. There's nothing unusual happening in that file.

The error:

```
| { Neo4jError: Connection was closed by server
|
|     at captureStacktrace (/code/node_modules/neo4j-driver/lib/v1/result.js:200:15)
|     at new Result (/code/node_modules/neo4j-driver/lib/v1/result.js:73:19)
|     at Session._run (/code/node_modules/neo4j-driver/lib/v1/session.js:173:14)
|     at Session.run (/code/node_modules/neo4j-driver/lib/v1/session.js:154:19)
|     at Object.complete (/code/datamigrations/003/0007_yet_another_script.js:34:17)
|     at ReadableStreamStreamer.ChunkStreamer.parseChunk (/code/node_modules/papaparse/papaparse.js:548:18)
|     at ReadableStreamStreamer.<anonymous> (/code/node_modules/papaparse/papaparse.js:857:11)
|     at ReadableStreamStreamer._streamData (/code/node_modules/papaparse/papaparse.js:1817:25)
|     at ReadableStreamStreamer.<anonymous> (/code/node_modules/papaparse/papaparse.js:876:9)
|     at IconvLiteEncoderStream.<anonymous> (/code/node_modules/papaparse/papaparse.js:1817:25) code: 'ServiceUnavailable', name: 'Neo4jError' }
```

The script itself does nothing out of the ordinary. The error occurs at the first session.run of the script:

```
    session.run(
      `UNWIND {batch} as row
       MATCH (e:Episode {issueKey: row.issueKey})
       WITH e,row
       UNWIND row.otherIds as otherId
       MATCH (a:OtherElement {id: otherId})
       CREATE (e)-[:ENABLES]->(a)
      `,
      { batch: elements },
```

Admittedly it's a big batch I'm creating here. Over 30k nodes. Could that cause the error? Would it be better to chunk this in batches of 10k or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, using smaller batches will probably help.

Also, your query can be simplified:

```
   UNWIND $batch as row
   MATCH (e:Episode {issueKey: row.issueKey}), (a:OtherElement)
   WHERE a.id IN row.otherIds
   CREATE (e)-[:ENABLES]->(a)
```

In addition, having [indexes](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/administration/indexes-for-search-performance/) on `:Episode(issueKey)` and `:OtherElement(id)` should improve performance.

Comment: This query is shorter, but is it really more efficient? You first match all OtherElements, before filtering most of them out again. Isn't matching directly by id more efficient?

I'll definitely add the indices. We don't have indices on all our labels yet, and I just did a test that shows it matters.

Comment: Very good question, which is why you should always do a [PROFILE](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.4/cypher/query-tuning/how-do-i-profile-a-query/) of your queries. With those 2 indexes, when I profile my query on neo4j 4.0.4, I see that both indexes are used. That means the query does *not* "match all OtherElements".